# "Unsafe assignment of an any value" when using react-transition-group with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-transition-group, react-typescript

I have various `@typescript-eslint` errors when using the `Transition` component from `react-transition-group`.

I followed the official React Transition Group small example for JS but with TypeScript + ESLint on my project I'm getting the following error: `Unsafe assignment of an any value`.

Another related error which is `element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type`.

```jsx
const transition = {
  transitionStyles: {
    entering: { opacity: 0, transform: 'translateX(0rem)' },
    entered: { opacity: 1, transform: 'translateX(0rem)' },
    exiting: { opacity: 1, transform: 'translateX(2rem)' },
    exited: { opacity: 0, transform: 'translateX(-2rem)' },
    unmounted: { opacity: 0, transform: 'translateX(-2rem)' },
  } as { [key: string]: React.CSSProperties },
};
```

```jsx
<Transition in timeout={700}>
  {(state) => (
    <div style={{ ...transition.transitionStyles[state] }}>
      /* ... */
    </div>
  )}
</Transition>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to cast the `state` variable as a string, because it's by default a `TransitionStatus` (declared from `react-transition-group`):

   ```jsx
   {(state: string) => (
     <div style={{ ...transition.transitionStyles[state] }}>
       /* ... */
     </div>
   )}
   ```
2. Then proceed to cast the `transitionStyles` `any object` into a typed object, which returns for each `key` a `React.CSSProperties` object. This can be done like this:

   ```jsx
   const transition = {
     transitionStyles: {
       entering: { opacity: 0, transform: 'translateX(0rem)' },
       entered: { opacity: 1, transform: 'translateX(0rem)' },
       exiting: { opacity: 1, transform: 'translateX(2rem)' },
       exited: { opacity: 0, transform: 'translateX(-2rem)' },
       unmounted: { opacity: 0, transform: 'translateX(-2rem)' },
     } as { [key: string]: React.CSSProperties }
   };
   ```